# Laravel public storage folder not found

Tags: php, laravel

Uploaded laravel project files to production server and ran `php artisan storage:link` command to create symlink to `public/storage` from `storage/app/public` folder and got message symlink created. But I forgot to delete the public storage folder from the local.

After uploading an image file, I could not access it and was getting 404 not found error exception. I then deleted the `public/storage` folder and ran `php artisan storage:link` again but got the message `The "public/storage" directory already exists.` but it's not there and I am not able to access images uploaded in the `storage/app/public/` folder.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this
rm -rf public/storage
Then run
php artisan storage:link